# Error en Array de objetos cuando le paso parámetro

Tags: javascript, java, java-swing, java-ee, java-8

Buenas compañeros en la programacion
alguien por favor podria asesorarme que estoy haciendo mal, en esta aplicacion.
ya que antes me funcionaba, pero la momento de cambiar un array de tipo entero a objeto
ciertas cosas se salieron de control
Gracias.............

Caballos  ArrCaballos = new  Caballos[2]   ..............................antes... global

Caballos  ArrCaballos = new  Caballos[nElementos].........................actual .....en el metodo

1 ..Al momento que cambie mi declaracion de array. ha tipo  objeto llamado ArrCaballo
.. al cual le paso como parametro una cantidad digitada por el usuario
me saca unos tipos de errores

por ejemplo
array required, but int found.
cannot find symbol.
symbol:   variable ArrCaballos.

```
array required, but int found

  Este error pertenece al ordenamiento de burbuja
```

Aqui mi codigo**************************

```
**public class Caballo** {
    
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
    private double alzada;
    private double peso;

    public Caballo() {
    }

    public Caballo(String nombre, int edad, double alzada, double peso) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.alzada = alzada;
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public double getAlzada() {
        return alzada;
    }

    public void setAlzada(double alzada) {
        this.alzada = alzada;
    }

    public double getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }

    public void setPeso(double peso) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }
        
    
}









public class ArrayConObjetos{

    
    static String nombre, aux;
    static int edad = 0, opcion = 0, suma=0;
    static double alzada = 0, peso = 0 ;
    static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
  
    static int nElementos;
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            do {            
                 opcion=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Seleccione una opción\n"
                         + "1.Ingresar caballos \n"
                         + "2. Promedio alzada \n"
                         + "3. Lista Ordenada \n"
                         + "4. Buscar caballo\n"
                         + "5. Salir"));
                 
                  switch(opcion){
                      case 1:
                           caballosIngresados();
                          break;
                          
                      case 2:
                          break;
                          
                          
                      case 3:
                       //  listaDeCaballosOrdenada(int parametro);
                             
                             break;
                             
                             
                      case 4:
                               Mensaje();
                          break;
                          
                          
                      case 5 : break;
                          //salir
                          default:
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "opcion incorrecta");
                              break;
                          
                          
                  }
                         
                 
                 
              } while (opcion !=5);
        
        
        
           
         
            //buscarRepetido(dato);

    }//*************main**************************
    
    
    
    public static void caballosIngresados(){
     
        
        
        System.out.println("Guardando los datos del arreglo ");
        
          nElementos=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite la cantidad de caballos ha 
 ingressar"));
           //ArrCaballos = new  int [nElementos];
             Caballo ArrCaballos[] = new Caballo[nElementos];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrCaballos.length; i++) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". Digite  un nombre del caballo: ");
            nombre = entrada.next();
            //Arrcaballos[i].setNombre("nombre");
            ArrCaballos[i] = new Caballo(nombre, edad, peso, alzada);
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". Digite la edad del cabalo: ");
            edad = entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". Digite el peso del caballo: ");
            peso = entrada.nextInt();

            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". Digite la alzada en metros:\n ");
            alzada = entrada.nextInt();
            
             System.out.println("------------****** *********------------------ ");  
        } 
        
        
        
       System.out.println("------------****** Mostrando los datos del arreglo *********------------------ ");  
        for(int i=0;i<ArrCaballos.length;i++){
            
            System.out.println("EL nombre del caballo es " + ArrCaballos[i].getNombre() +"\n"
                    + "La edad del caballo es:" + ArrCaballos[i].getEdad()+ "\n "
                    + "El peso del caballo es:" + ArrCaballos[i].getPeso() +"\n" 
                    + "La alzada en metros es:" + ArrCaballos[i].getAlzada()+"" );
             System.out.println("------------******  *********------------------ ");  
        }
         Mensaje();
    }
    
    
     public void alzadaPromedio(Object Caballo){
        float promedio=0;
        int suma=0;
        
         for(int i=0; i<nElementos;i++){
             //suma+=nElementos.getAlzada();
         }
        
        promedio=(suma/nElementos);
         System.out.println("El promedio de alzada de los caballos es;" + promedio);
        
    }   
    
    
    
  /*  public  static void buscarRepetido(String dato){
        boolean existe=false;
        if(dato.equals(nombre)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre ya existe");
        }else{
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre no existe");
        }
    }
    */
    
    public static void listaDeCaballosOrdenada(int parametro){
        caballosIngresados(); //llamo al objeto qur tiene toda la data
        
                             //debo ordenarlo segun su alzada, por metodo burbuja
    }
    
    
  

      public static void Mensaje(){
            
            System.out.println("Buscar caballo por nombre");
            String datoBuscar = entrada.next();
            
            //int posicion = -1;
            
            
               // ordenar metod burbuja segun su alzada (metros)
    
               for(int i=0; i<(nElementos-1;i++){
                    for(int j=0; j<(nElementos-1);j++){
                        if(nElementos[j] > nElementos[j+1]){ // aca la condicion es, si numero actual arr[j] es mayor al numero siguiente  arr[j+1]
                            aux= nElementos[j];
                            nElementos[j] = nElementos[j+1]; // el numero actual es igual al siguiente
                            ArrCaballos[j+1]= aux;    
                        }
                    }
                }  
            
            
            
            
            for(int i=0;i<nElementos;i++){
                if(datoBuscar.equals(nElementos[i].getNombre())){
                    
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  " El caballo ya existe \n" + "su nombre es:" +ArrCaballos[i].getNombre() + "\n"
                     + "La edad del caballo es:" + ArrCaballos[i].getEdad()+ "\n "
                        + "El peso del caballo es:" + ArrCaballos[i].getPeso() +"\n" 
                        + "La alzada en metros es:" + ArrCaballos[i].getAlzada()+"" );
                 System.out.println("------------******  *********------------------ "); 
                   
                }else{
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  " El caballo No existe"  + "");
                }
            }
       
       
        
        
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a la siguiente instrucción, ya que intentas acceder al índice de una variable de tipo int, y no a un array.

```
if(nElementos[j] > nElementos[j+1]){...}
```

nElementos es de tipo int según has declarado

```
static int nElementos;
```

Te recomiendo que para próximas preguntas evites subir todo el código, solamente las partes relevantes (evita getters, métodos sin errores...)

Comment: muchas gracias por responder, verificare lo observado de tu parte, y tendré presente lo recomendado al momento de formular una nueva pregunta